# SQL join on condition

Tags: sql, if-statement, join, conditional-statements, case

I am trying to join a field (in table 1) to table 2 or table 3 depending on the value of a another field in table 1.

My COMM table (1) looks like this:

```
CommID  User ID  Type
100     987      SER
101     123      EMP
```

`SER` (2) and `EMP` (3) will give me information about those Users.  I need to join the `User ID` from the COMM table to `SER` and `EMP` dependent on the `Type` field in `COMMM`.  This is NOT working but may illustrate what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT *
CASE 
   WHEN comm.type = 'SER' THEN ser.userName 
   ELSE emp.userName
END
FROM COMM
LEFT JOIN SER on SER.userID = comm.UserID and comm.type = 'SER'
LEFT JOIN EMP on EMP.userID = comm.UserID and comm.type = 'EMP'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 2):

You should limit the `*` columns to just the columns from `comm`, and then add the column from the other table(s):

```
select comm.*,
CASE WHEN comm.type = 'SER' THEN ser.userName ELSE emp.userName END
FROM COMM
LEFT JOIN SER on SER.userID = comm.UserID and comm.type = 'SER'
LEFT JOIN EMP on EMP.userID = comm.UserID and comm.type = 'EMP'
```

Comment: I do have a comma after the *. I just left it out of this.  The statement's syntax is correct. I am getting results.  It's just the results are not right.  I am getting the correct aswer for a row with the EMP in the Type, but am getting NULL for the value in a row that I know has SER in the Type.

Comment: Keep in mind, this will return all columns from both the SER and EMP tables. You might want this to actually be "SELECT COMM.*," in order to just select all columns from just COMM.

Comment: The syntax looks correct.  Which fields are you getting a null for?  Do you have a matching record in the SER table?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use `UNION` -- probalby `UNION ALL` in this case:

```
SELECT 
  comm.*,
  ser.userName
FROM 
  comm
  JOIN 
    SER 
  ON 
     SER.userID = comm.UserID
WHERE
  comm.type = 'SER'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  comm.*,
  emp.userName
FROM 
  coom
  JOIN 
    emp 
  ON 
     emp.userID = comm.UserID
WHERE
  comm.type = 'EMP'
;
```

This will work in types in both tables are compatible (in case of user name they should).

`UNION ALL` selects all rows from both `SELECTS` -- it not excludes duplicates (which here, I assume, could be not real duplicates).

Comment: I can see where a UNION would get what I need, but this is a very small part of a much larger query so I was hoping for something less convoluted :(

Comment: I figured out my problem. I was using the wrong field.  ARRRGGHHH!!! problem solved. thanks!